# using java for XML data set in biology

Tags: java, xml

I wrote a code in java for parsing an xml file that meant to be used. and now i have problem. my data set is AIMed and is something like this:

```xml
<passage>
    <text>
        Isolation of human delta-catenin and its binding specificity with presenilin 1.
        We screened proteins for interaction with presenilin (PS) 1, and cloned the full-length cDNA of human delta-catenin, which encoded 1225 amino acids.
        Yeast two-hybrid assay, GST binding assay and immunoprecipitation demonstrated that delta-catenin interacted with a hydrophilic loop region in the endoproteolytic C-terminal fragment of PS1, but not with that of PS-2.
        These results suggest that PS1 and PS2 partly differ in function.
        PS1 loop fragment containing the pathogenic mutation retained the binding ability.
        We also found another armadillo-protein, p0071, interacted with PS1.
    </text>
    <annotation id="T1">
        <infon key="file">ann</infon>
        <infon key="type">protein</infon>
        <location offset="19" length="13"></location>
        <text>delta-catenin</text>
    </annotation>
    <relation id="R3">
        <infon key="relation type">Interaction</infon>
        <infon key="file">ann</infon>
        <infon key="type">Relation</infon>
        <node refid="T5" role="Arg1"></node>
        <node refid="T6" role="Arg2"></node>
    </relation>
</passage>
```

and i'm using `SAXParser` and my code is like this(for text tag):

```
else if (bText) 
{
     System.out.println("Text: " 
     + new String(ch, start, length));
     bText = false;
}
```

but it shows only two senteces. my question is how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Walk through the nodes in your NodeList until you find the corresponding node, cast it to an element (in your case text), then use element.getTextContent().
See for it [Interface Node](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html), and think that it will also return the text of the node descendants (if they exist).